# Remove text that is in the middle of <b></b>

Tags: php, regex

I Have Text in the middle of  `<b></b>` Eg:

```
La  <b>la</b>: the  1  <br></br>Aventuroj  <b>aventuro</b>: adventure  2  <br></br>de  <b>de</b>: by, from, of, since  3  <br></br>Mirlando  <b>miri</b>: marvel, marvel at, wonder<br/><b>lando</b>: country, land  4  <br></br>by  <b>ba</b>: bah, nuts, pooh  5  <br></br>for  <b>for</b>: away  6  <br></br>
```

I would like maybe a regex that would strip the text and the `<b></b>` from the string

Thanks

★✩

Comment: This reminds me of a semi-famous post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php):

```
$output = preg_replace('!<b>.*?</b>!s', '', $input);
```

The `s` on the end is a flag. See [Pattern Modifiers](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php) for a list of flags.

> **s** (PCRE_DOTALL)
>
> If this modifier is set, a dot
>   metacharacter in the pattern matches
>   all characters, including newlines.
>   Without it, newlines are excluded.
>   This modifier is equivalent to Perl's
>   /s modifier. A negative class such as
>   [^a] always matches a newline
>   character, independent of the setting
>   of this modifier.

Generally speaking however regexes are a poor tool for querying and manipulating HTML or XML. PHP has a number of inbuilt HTML parsers and for a robust solution you should use those instead, as a general rule.

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace("/<b>(.*?)<\/b>/ism","",$str);
```